# Visual studio 2017 - Memory snapshot empty

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to use the memory profiler in VS 2017 Pro but although I am able to take a memory snapshot, when I try to visualize it, it is just empty, as you can see on the screenshot.

Am I missing something ?

[[image]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbVA0.png)

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use the memory profiler in VS 2017 Pro but although I
>   am able to take a memory snapshot, when I try to visualize it, it is
>   just empty, as you can see on the screenshot.

The default **Native Window** will ignore these Unresolved Allocations.

You should uncheck the checkbox filter called **Hide Unresolved Allocations**.

Follow these gif's operation and you will see the content later.

[image]